# How to avoid too many queries to the database in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, performance

Among methods: static variables, viewstate, session and cache for avoiding on loading repeatedly and less making queries to the database.

What do you think the best method of the 4 above? I think cache is the best one? Or any other methods better in Asp.net 3.5 or higher?

Comment: I agree with you, because it can manage it's own memory (purge when required).  If your using SQL server with .NET, you can use SqlCacheDependency to keep your Cache & DB Data in sync!

Comment: All of the above are caching solutions. They only differ at context. Static variables caches the data in-memory during the lifetime of the Appdomain, so usually all users can use it. Viewstate caches serialized data at the user and for that response/request only. Session caches data (in-memory or serialized depending on session storage) for the current user only.

Comment: Single Web Server or Web Farm?  What kind of load balancing?  Sticky or not?  These will all make a difference to the 'right' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data being retrieved is user specific, consider using Session. If it's the same data shared among all users, consider using the cache.

I'd discourage using view state to cache database results because it quickly inflates the size of the rendered markup. On top of that, view state content must not only be downloaded but also is POSTed back to the server when the form is submitted, so with view state you pay the performance penalty twice.

Another option you didn't mention is to use the HttpContext.Items collection. This makes for a great way to cache database data *per-request*. This technique is quite helpful if you have many separate modules in a page (such as the master page and User Controls) that are retrieving the same data, as it allows that data to be requested once and then cached for the lifetime of that particular request. For more information, refer to [HttpContext.Items - a Per-Request Cache Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to your question. A sound data-access strategy that is designed to be scalable and perform well will likely involve several or even all of the tools you mention, and possibly others.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you will not use viewState when you need persistent data throught an entire session, nor will you save per-user data in you application object.

viewState - per page 
Session - per session (per user) 
Application - per application 
Cookie - per user (but not per session - rather throughout sessions)

You would usually use the Cache object to cache objects in application level..

That's about it.. Each has a different role.